# Docker how to run pip requirements.txt only if there was a change?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

In a Dockerfile I have a layer which installs `requirements.txt`:

```
FROM python:2.7
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

When I build the docker image it runs the whole process **regardless** of any changes made to this file.

How do I make sure Docker only runs `pip install -r requirements.txt` if there has been a change to the file?

```
Removing intermediate container f98c845d0f05
Step 3 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 8ceb63abaef6
Collecting https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/archive/master.zip (from -r requirements.txt (line 30))
  Downloading https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/archive/master.zip
Collecting Django==1.8.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Comment: Please post the output of `docker build` (and your `Dockerfile`). Presumably, it's an earlier step in your build process that's busting the cache, causing this step to run.

Comment: update OP with all i have in at the moment

Comment: Just this step isn't useful. Please post the *complete* output (or at least the Dockerfile).

Answer (score 281, accepted):

I'm assuming that at some point in your build process, you're copying your entire application into the Docker image with `COPY` or `ADD`:

```
COPY . /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The problem is that you're invalidating the Docker build cache every time you're copying the entire application into the image. This will also invalidate the cache for all subsequent build steps.

To prevent this, I'd suggest copying **only the `requirements.txt`** file in a separate build step before adding the entire application into the image:

```
COPY requirements.txt /opt/app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /opt/app
# continue as before...
```

As the requirements file itself probably changes only rarely, you'll be able to use the cached layers up until the point that you add your application code into the image.

Comment: As a general guideline, I believe `COPY` is preferred over `ADD` unless you specifically need the behavior of `ADD`.

Comment: @Metropolis, you're entirely correct. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Agree with @Metropolis. `ADD` is only needed if `<src>` folder is containing any archive that needs to be unpacked or need to support remote URL handling. [**{source code}**](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/670c8696a29825b23208496bd4d8e88b5faa7773/builder/dispatchers.go#L77)

Comment: "As the requirements file itself probably changes only rarely" - if only during dev... :(

Answer (score 74):

This is directly mentioned in Docker's own "[Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)":

> If you have multiple Dockerfile steps that use different files from
> your context, COPY them individually, rather than all at once. This
> will ensure that each step’s build cache is only invalidated (forcing
> the step to be re-run) if the specifically required files change.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
> RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt
> COPY . /tmp/
> ```
>
> results in fewer cache invalidations for the RUN step, than if you put
> the COPY . /tmp/ before it.

Answer (score -4):

Alternatively as a quicker means to run `requirements.txt` file without typing "yes" to confirm installation of libraries, you can re-write as:

```
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -y -r requirements.txt
COPY ./"dir"/* .
```

Comment: What is this an alternative to?

Also I don't remember ever having to type "yes" when doing a docker build.

I'm sorry, I fail to see the relation of this answer the question