# How to prevent Docker from re-running pip installs every time I modify code

Tags: docker, pip, dockerfile

I have a scraper with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
# Adapted from trcook/docker-scrapy
FROM python:alpine
RUN apk --update add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev gcc musl-dev libgcc openssl-dev
COPY . /scraper
RUN pip install -r /scraper/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /scraper/apkmirror_scraper
CMD ["scrapy", "crawl", "apkmirror"]
```

The code for the scraper is located in `/scraper/apkmirror_scraper`, and the requirements in `scraper/requirements.txt`. I've noticed that every time I modify the code and build the image, it re-runs the `pip install -r requirements.txt` rather than using the local cache.

How can I prevent this and make it use the local cache?

(One 'theory' about this is that whereas `/scraper/requirements.txt` itself hasn't changed, the `/scraper` directory has, which makes the `RUN` directive have to 're-run'; in this case it might help to move `requirements.txt` to a different directory. I wasn't able to verify whether this 'theory' is correct from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run, however).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question, [Docker how to run pip requirements.txt only if there was a change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398632/docker-how-to-run-pip-requirements-txt-only-if-there-was-a-change), seems to pertain to my situation. Every time I modify the code I invalidate the Docker build cache, even though `requirements.txt` is unchanged. So to avoid having to re-run `pip install`s every time, it is recommended to `COPY` the `requirements.txt` and `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` in a separate step.

Comment: Not helpful. It is still running pip install if I add a single new library in the requirements.txt. I want it to install only the new library.