# i get a wrong when i build a dockerfile i have no idea for it

Tags: python, docker

I'm run docker in windows10 ,my dockerfile like this

```
FROM python:2.7-slim

WORKDIR E:/docker

ADD . E:/docker

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

ENV NAME World

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

when i run
 `docker build -t friendlyhello .` 
i get a wrong like this:

```
E:\docker-demo>docker build -t friendlyhello .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB

Step 1/7 : FROM python:2.7-slim

 ---> d0d1b97dd328

Step 2/7 : WORKDIR E:/docker

 ---> Using cache

 ---> 305b573b82a5

Step 3/7 : ADD . E:/docker

 ---> 6d25bd33ba84

Step 4/7 : RUN pip install -r E:/docker-demo/requirements.txt

 ---> Running in e68dd3cd1c71
```

`Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:` `'E:/docker-demo/requirements.txt'`

```
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r E:/docker-demo/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

it make the RUN as `/bin/sh -c`. but it shoud be `cmd /S /C` in windows
,and it can be worked when I run the `pip install -r requirements.txt` at commonds lines direct.I have no idea how to resove it.thanks for answer

Comment: it worked with your Suggest!  thanks very mach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `E:/docker` with `/tmp/` (any suitable path in form of linux directory structure) in dockerfile and execute 
`docker build -t friendlyhello .`

my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7-slim

WORKDIR /tmp/

ADD . /tmp/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

ENV NAME World

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Answer (score 2):

`requirements.txt` should be present at the same location where your docker file is

Comment: yes,there're in the same location. it can be worked when I run the code pip install -r requirements.txt  at  the commond,

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to specify the full path to the requirements.txt and make sure that it exists

Comment: can you try copying the requirements.txt inside the docker image? As proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398632/docker-how-to-run-pip-requirements-txt-only-if-there-was-a-change

Comment: hello ,I have modify it

Answer (score 0):

You have to find correct context for docker to start from.
Try navigating to parent folder and use -f argument of "docker build" to specify path to Dockerfile:

```
cd ../ParentFolder
docker build -f ../ParentFolder/ChildFolder/Dockerfile -t imagename .
```

Otherwise, try editing your Dockerfile