# Persist Package Installations in Python-based Docker Container

Tags: python, docker

I have a Python app running in a Docker container. I want to have the flexibility of installing new packages while the container is running. Eventually, I want to do this via the GUI, but right now I am doing it using the following commands,

```
docker exec -it container-name sh
pip install <package-name>
exit
docker restart container-name
```

This is fine for now, but I want these package installations to persist across stops and restarts of the container. How can I do this?

Comment: I'd suggest doing day-to-day development in a non-Docker virtual environment.  When you're ready to do integration testing in a container, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to get the current package list, commit that file to source control, and rebuild your image from the updated package list.

Comment: I do not have this option at the moment. I have an application that consists of multiple integrations and I want the dependencies for these integrations to only be installed on demand. Otherwise, the Docker image gets way too bulky and difficult to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new Docker Container from Docker Image, then the Docker engine will create for it a TMP area to store the data of container. That area is kept while the container is available. It means if you stop/start or re-start a container then the installed Python package will be available in the container. The Docker uses the same container after stop/start and re-start.

**For example:**

```bash
docker run -d python:3.11 yes # Start the Python container
docker exec -it 27a4dcfe37df bash # Enter to the Docker container
root@27a4dcfe37df:/# python3 # Verify the "configobj" module is not installed
Python 3.11.7 (main, Feb  1 2024, 04:37:50) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from configobj import ConfigObj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'configobj'
>>> exit()
root@27a4dcfe37df:/# pip3 install configobj. # Install "configobj" module
...
Successfully installed configobj-5.0.8 six-1.16.0
...
root@27a4dcfe37df:/# python3 # Verify the "configobj" module is available after PIP install
Python 3.11.7 (main, Feb  1 2024, 04:37:50) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from configobj import ConfigObj
>>>
```

**Stop/start the container:**

```
-> docker stop 27a4dcfe37df  # Stop the Python container
27a4dcfe37df
-> docker start 27a4dcfe37df # Start the Python container
27a4dcfe37df
-> docker exec -it 27a4dcfe37df bash
root@27a4dcfe37df:/# python3. # Verify if the "configobj" module is available after stop/start the container.
Python 3.11.7 (main, Feb  1 2024, 04:37:50) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from configobj import ConfigObj
>>>
```

**Restart the container:**

```
-> docker exec -it 27a4dcfe37df bash
root@27a4dcfe37df:/# python3 # Verify if the "configobj" module is available after re-start the container.
Python 3.11.7 (main, Feb  1 2024, 04:37:50) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from configobj import ConfigObj
>>>
```

You can persist the data via [Docker Volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) on your host machine. It means if you have a new container (Eg.: after `docker container rm -f <container_id>`) with the same volume, then the new container will see the previously installed Python packages. So you should persist that area [where the PIP installs the packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages).

However, I recommend to use the `requirements.txt` for the required Python modules. You can do it easily in Docker, some hints: [Docker how to run pip requirements.txt only if there was a change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398632/docker-how-to-run-pip-requirements-txt-only-if-there-was-a-change)